# Remove missing files in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Is there a quick way to remove only files that are missing in a Visual Studio project?  So files that are no longer accessible that were either deleted or moved outside of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you've physically deleted a file that an MSVS project still "remembers".

You can probably just select and delete the project items in question in the MSVS IDE.

Personally, I'd just edit the project file (e.g. "myprog.csproj") in Notepad.

Comment: Yes but this is very tedious.  I have many files included from many directories.  I'm wondering if there is a way just to remove all missing files.

Comment: @BerryBlue maybe create a new project file, add the entire directory, then edit the raw XML to migrate what you want to keep (settings, debug confit, etc)